# DataAdapter Update issue

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataadapter

The following coding doesn't update my table. But rows variable value is 1 after updating.
I cannot understand what is the cause behind this. Please help.

```
SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection1.Open();

var wktbl = new DataTable();

var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Test", connection1);
var da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var b = new SqlCommandBuilder(da1);
da1.Fill(wktbl);

wktbl.Rows[0][2] = "5";
da1.UpdateCommand = b.GetUpdateCommand(true);

int rows = da1.Update(wktbl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/33y2221y(v=vs.100).aspx) out. It shows the example below of doing an update with the dataadapter.

> The following examples demonstrate how to perform updates to modified rows by explicitly setting the UpdateCommand of a DataAdapter and calling its Update method. Notice that the parameter specified in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement is set to use the Original value of the SourceColumn. This is important, because the Current value may have been modified and may not match the value in the data source. The Original value is the value that was used to populate the DataTable from the data source.

```
private static void AdapterUpdate(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection =
           new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdpater = new SqlDataAdapter(
      "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories",
      connection);

    dataAdpater.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(
       "UPDATE Categories SET CategoryName = @CategoryName " +
       "WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID", connection);

    dataAdpater.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
       "@CategoryName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15, "CategoryName");

    SqlParameter parameter = dataAdpater.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
      "@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int);
    parameter.SourceColumn = "CategoryID";
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

    DataTable categoryTable = new DataTable();
    dataAdpater.Fill(categoryTable);

    DataRow categoryRow = categoryTable.Rows[0];
    categoryRow["CategoryName"] = "New Beverages";

    dataAdpater.Update(categoryTable);

    Console.WriteLine("Rows after update.");
    foreach (DataRow row in categoryTable.Rows)
    {
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", row[0], row[1]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's because connectionString has |DataDirectory|.
The MDF file location is different when running the application.